# How to check the validity of a GUID (or UUID) using NSRegularExpression or any other effective way in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

The method should return TRUE if the NSString is something like @"{A5B8A206-E14D-429B-BEB0-2DD0575F3BC0}" and FALSE for a NSString like @"bla bla bla"

I am using something like:

```
- (BOOL)isValidGUID {

    NSError *error;

    NSRange range = [[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:(\\()|(\\{))?\\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Z0-9]{12}\\b(?(1)\\))(?(2)\\})" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error] rangeOfFirstMatchInString:self.GUID options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.GUID length])];

    if (self.GUID && range.location != NSNotFound && [self.GUID length] == 38) {

        return TRUE;

    } else {

        return NO;
    }
}
```

but it is not working as I have expected.

Important: GUID which I am using is enclosed by curly braces like this: {A5B8A206-E14D-429B-BEB0-2DD0575F3BC0}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex matches for me

```
\A\{[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}\}\Z
```

In short:

- `\A` and `\Z` is the beginning and end of the string
- `\{` and `\}` is escaped curly bracets
- `[A-F0-9]{8}` is exactly 8 characters of either 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F

As an NSRegularExpression it would look like this

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\A\\{[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}\\}\\Z" 
                                            options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines 
                                              error:&error];
// use the regex to match the string ...
```

Answer (score 30):

This function will do the job..

```
-(BOOL)isValidUUID : (NSString *)UUIDString
{
     return (bool)[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:U‌​UIDString]; 
}
```

Thanks @Erzékiel

Comment: Works fine for me !
It could be minimized like this : return (bool)[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:UUIDString];

Comment: Thanks. This should be an accepted answer. Works fine on iOS 9.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method to check this:

```
- (BOOL)isUUID:(NSString *)inputStr
{
    BOOL isUUID = FALSE;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:inputStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputStr length])];
    if(matches == 1)
    {
       isUUID = TRUE;
    }
    return isUUID;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider the shortened UUID format. Use code below:

```
-（BOOL)isValidUUID:(NSString*)uuidString{   
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
if (uuid ) {
    return YES;
}

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^0-9|^a-f]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [reg matchesInString:uuidString options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, uuidString.length)];

if (matches.count == 0 && (uuidString.length == 4 || uuidString.length ==8) ) {
    return YES;
}else{
    return NO;
}
}
```