# UUIDWithString crash when input invalid param

Tags: ios, uuid

When I use `[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"xxx"]`, something like that the invalid uuid string, the app will crash.
How to check if the param is a valid UUID-format.

The error is:

> Assertion failure in -[CBUUID initWithString:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MobileBluetoothFramework/MobileBluetooth-115.5.1/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth/CBUUID.m:149

I can't understand why the assertion happens on release version. Maybe Apple forget to turn off assertion switch.

Comment: where are you getting the UUID from, the system or are you creating one?

Comment: The inputed  UUID may from anywhere, but I need to make sure the app can't be crashed. So  I have to make sure the input string is a valid format before I call UUIDWithString

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)isUUID:(NSString *)string
{
   return !![[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:string]; 
}
```

Comment: YES， it can validate the full uuid format, but if you use '0FFE'  the short term, the NSUUID will return nil.

Comment: @zedzhao in that case you may need to just to a regex yourself, check out this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652833/how-to-check-the-validity-of-a-guid-or-uuid-using-nsregularexpression-or-any-o

Comment: What's the use of `!!` here?

Comment: @rmaddy double cast to bool

Comment: Why not use `return [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:string] != nil;`

Comment: @rmaddy ya you’re right, been in JS land too long today, I’ll update when I get back

Comment: The regex can't validate shortened format, like '0FFE' is valid but '0FFFF' is invalid.

Comment: @zedzhao check the length then first?

Comment: seems there is no better way.